# How to find value of $\vec{u}\cdot(\vec{v}×\vec{w})$?

Tags: vectors

Let $u$ and $v$ be unit vectors and $\vec{w}$ is a vector(not necessarily unit vector)  such $\vec{u}×\vec{v}+\vec{u}=\vec{w}$ and $\vec{w}×u=v$,then how to find value of $\vec{u}\cdot(\vec{v}×\vec{w})$ ?

What would be the best and shortest approach to this problem? Should I assume certain angles between the vectors say $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and try subtituting in the equations? But that is too long. Help needed.

Comment: $u.(v\times w)$ is called the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product

Comment: @Michael is the answer 1?

Comment: Why do you think so?...

Comment: I got it after some random manipulations :-P @Michael

Comment: Well, there you go :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: the triple product is invariant under cyclic permutations of the three vectors.

More details as requested: since the triple product is invariant under cyclic permutations,

$$u\cdot (v \times w) = v \cdot (w \times u) = v \cdot v = 1.$$

Notice that the other condition $u \times v + u = w$ is unneeded here.

Comment: +1: This is by far the most elegant answer. Would you mind fleshing it out, now that other step-by-step solutions have been posted?

Comment: Thanks - this is a nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

Since $\vec{w}=\vec{u}\times\vec{v}+\vec{u}$ it follows
\begin{align}
\vec{v}\times\vec{w}&=\vec{v}\times\left(\vec{u}\times\vec{v}\right)+\vec{v}\times\vec{u}\\
&=\left(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}\right)\vec{u}-\left(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{u}\right)\vec{v}+\vec{v}\times\vec{u}\qquad\quad\text{from the properties of the cross product}\\
&=\vec{u}-\left(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{u}\right)\vec{v}+\vec{v}\times\vec{u}\qquad\qquad\quad\;\;\,\text{since }\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}=\left\|\vec{v}\right\|^2=1\\
&=\vec{u}+\vec{v}\times\vec{u}
\end{align}
Cause $\vec{w}\times\vec{u}=\vec{v}$ implies $\vec{v}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{u}$ and so $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{u}=0$, thus

\begin{align}
\vec{u}\cdot\left(\vec{v}\times\vec{w}\right)&=\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}+\vec{u}\cdot\left(\vec{v}\times\vec{u}\right)\\
&=\left\|\vec{u}\right\|^2+0\qquad\qquad\quad\text{cause }\vec{u}\times\vec{v}\,\text{ is perpendicular to }\vec{u}\\
&=1
\end{align}

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Could you please explain how you got the expression for $\vec{u}\cdot(\vec{v}\times\vec{w})$.

Comment: @user84413: By using the properties of the dot product.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how did you know you could use $\vec{w}$  in place of $\vec{v}\times\vec{w}$?

Answer (score 2):

$v×w=(w×u)×w=(w.w)u-(w.u)w$ using property of vector triple product.

Now $w.u=(u×v+u).u=0+1=1$

and,

$w.w=(u×v).(u×v)+u.u=1+1=2$

Hence,required result is $u.[(w.w)u-(w.u)w]=2.1-1.1=1$

Comment: Could you please explain how you got $(\vec{u}\times\vec{v})\cdot(\vec{u}\times\vec{v})=1$.  (It is correct.)

Comment: (u×v) is an unit vector perpendicular to 2 unit vectors u and v.So the dot product of the new unit vector with itself is 1. @user84413

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  (This is right, but I think you're using that u and v are orthogonal when you say $u\times v$ is a unit vector.)

Comment: You are right @user84413 .My mistake.

Comment: u.v=u.(w×u)=0....i hope it clear now @user84413

Comment: Yes, you were right; I just wanted to understand how you got it.

Answer (score 2):

$\vec{v}\times\vec{w}=\vec{v}\times(\vec{u}\times\vec{v})+\vec{v}\times\vec{u}=(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v})\vec{u}-(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{u})\vec{v}+\vec{v}\times\vec{u}=\vec{u}+\vec{v}\times\vec{u},\;$ so

$\vec{u}\cdot(\vec{v}\times\vec{w})=\vec{u}\cdot(\vec{u}+\vec{v}\times\vec{u})=\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}+\vec{u}\cdot(\vec{v}\times\vec{u})=1+0=1$

(using that $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}=1, \vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}=1$, and $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=0$)

Comment: I would just like to point out that $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = 0$ isn't given, but follows from $\vec{v} = \vec{w} \times \vec{u}$.

Comment: @A.P. You're right, and that's what I was using.